# Why is my SwiftUI .onChange modifier not picking up a @Binding change?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, binding, onchange

I'm in the process of building an application that fetches and decodes some data from an API. Some of the data returned are booleans that I want to allow the user to toggle (using a `Toggle` view).

Once toggled, I'd like an action to be performed (writing back to the server). I was previously doing this via the `onChange` modifier but have since needed a deeper set of `View` objects in my view hierarchy, which has led me to pass @Binding properties down into these views.

As soon as I hit a view depth of **three**, the `onChange` is not triggered. I hope the below example code illustrates the problem sufficiently (I realise the terminology used isn't correct, just an example.)

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct CPU: Hashable {
    let name: String
    var runners: [Runner]
}

struct Runner: Hashable {
    let name: String
    var isRunning: Bool
}

struct RunnersView: View {
    @Binding var runners: [Runner]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach($runners, id: \.self) { $runner in
                Toggle(runner.name, isOn: $runner.isRunning)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: runners) { newValue in
            print("runners changed in RunnersView:")
            print(runners)
        }
    }
}

struct CPUView: View {
    @Binding var cpu: CPU
    
    var body: some View {
        Section(cpu.name) {
            RunnersView(runners: $cpu.runners)
        }
        .onChange(of: cpu) { newValue in
            print("cpu changed in CPUView:")
            print(cpu)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var cpus = [
        CPU(name: "CPU 1", runners: [
            Runner(name: "Runner 1", isRunning: false),
            Runner(name: "Runner 2", isRunning: false),
            Runner(name: "Runner 3", isRunning: false),
        ]),
        CPU(name: "CPU 2", runners: [
            Runner(name: "Runner 4", isRunning: false),
            Runner(name: "Runner 5", isRunning: false),
            Runner(name: "Runner 6", isRunning: false),
        ]),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List($cpus, id: \.self) { $cpu in
                CPUView(cpu: $cpu)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onChange(of: cpus, perform: { newValue in
            print("cpus changed in ContentView:")
            print(cpus)
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The above code triggers the `onChange` in `ContentView` when a toggle is changed, but not in the other views.

I've tried double checking all the @Binding declarations are correct, and changing some to @State, but admittedly I'm fairly new to SwiftUI.

Comment: You need to print `newValue`. `onChange` fires on `willChange` and not `didSet`

Comment: Printing `newValue` doesn't seem to change anything. The issue is that `onChange` isn't getting called at all in `CPUView` or `RunnersView`. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: It looks like it's a new instance of `RunnersView` altogether, as confirmed by printing on `onAppear`. Not exactly sure why the identity is changing.

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you're saying. I'd assume `RunnersView` is getting recreated because the `ContentView`'s state changes as a result of the toggle change.

Weirdly though, if you take out the CPU view and just pass an array of runners to a `RunnersView` from `ContentView`, the `RunnersView` does not get recreated on a toggle change.

Comment: Like so:
```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var runners = [
        Runner(name: "Runner 1", isRunning: false),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        RunnersView(runners: $runners)
        .onChange(of: runners, perform: { newValue in
            print("runners changed in ContentView:")
            print(runners)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`id: \.self` is invalid, the `id` param needs to be a unique identifier property or better have your model struct conform to `Identifiable` by implementing an `id`, e.g.

```
struct Runner: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() // for Identifiable conformance
     
    // or compute a unique id, e.g.
    // var id: String {
    //      name + dob + city etc.
    // }

...

ForEach($runners) { $runner in
```

See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach) for more info

> ...Either the collection’s elements must conform to Identifiable or
> you need to provide an id parameter to the ForEach initializer.

Comment: I'm providing the `id` parameter to the `ForEach` initialiser, which is an alternative to having my struct conform to `Identifiable`.

Comment: You might be providing the id parameter but you aren't providing an actual identifier because your Runner struct is missing an identifier var.